# STM32F303: Clock sporadically dies away

Tags: stm32, oscillator

The clock of my [STM32F303CC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303vc.pdf) (links to datasheet; for reference manual see [here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4a/19/6e/18/9d/92/43/32/DM00043574.pdf/files/DM00043574.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00043574.pdf)) sporadically dies away, resulting in highly decreased code execution speed (see picture below). I already replaced the oscillator and experimented with different capacitor values. I also tested this on different boards, all exhibiting the same error.

The firmware of the STM32 always runs the same lines of code, so transitions in firmware code can't be the reason.

The components used are:

- Oscillator: [7A-8.000MAAE-T](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/417/7a-13881.pdf)
- Capacitors: 2x 22pF, 6V3, 0603, C0G

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit**: Replaced layout image as I forgot to render polygons.

**Edit**: The decoupling capacitors are on the direct opposite of the board, just beneath the STM, and are connected through vias with both top's GND and 3V3 pins (former through PCB wire, latter through the copper plane).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I see unconnected VDD, VDDA and VBAT pins in your circuit. You need to connect *all* those power pins to the chip.

VDDA might be the culprit here, as the crystal OSC might actually be powered by this pin.

Comment: I'm very sorry, that's my mistake. I forgot to render the polygons before taking the screenshot. I will update the picture as soon as possible. But all those pins mentioned by you are actually connected.

Comment: AN4206, chapter 5.4: Decoupling caps are missing or too far away to funtion properly.

Comment: The decoupling capacitors are on the direct opposite of the board, just beneath the STM, and are connected through vias with both top's GND and 3V3 pins (former through PCB wire, latter through the copper plane).